# How is this parameter in constructor used in member method directly in FSharp?

Tags: .net, oop, functional-programming, f#, .net-core

This example (counter example) is given in the "Removing Cyclic Dependencies" of FSharp for fun and profit. https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/removing-cyclic-dependencies/.

```
type Customer(name, observer:CustomerObserver) = 
        let mutable name = name
        member this.Name 
            with get() = name
            and set(value) = 
                name <- value
                observer.OnNameChanged(this)

and CustomerObserver() = 
    member this.OnNameChanged(c:Customer) =     
        printfn "Customer name changed to '%s' " c.Name
```

See the parameter `observer` in the `Customer` class. It is not declared as a field or property in the type. What is it then?

Comment: I believe all constructor arguments are implicitly stored in fields with the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, args from the constructor are in scope throughout the class declaration. This differs from C# and VB.

It is mentioned in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/classes#constructors).

> The arguments of the primary constructor are in scope throughout the class declaration.